# SELECT Statement Involving Three Different Tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, greatest-n-per-group

**Note:** I was unsure how to title this, if anybody has a better idea feel free to change it.

---

My database currently has the following tables (some columns and other details have been removed from the output of the commands shown, but they should not be relevant):

```
webserver=> \d+ team

   Column    |          Type          |                     Modifiers                     | Storage  
-------------+------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+----------
 id          | integer                | not null default nextval('team_id_seq'::regclass) | plain     
 name        | character varying(255) | not null                                          | extended  
Indexes:
    "team_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "team_name" UNIQUE, btree (name)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "challengesolve" CONSTRAINT "challengesolve_team_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (team_id) REFERENCES team(id)

webserver=> \d+ challenge

       Column       |          Type          |                       Modifiers                        | Storage  
--------------------+------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+----------
 id                 | integer                | not null default nextval('challenge_id_seq'::regclass) | plain     
 name               | character varying(255) | not null                                               | extended  
 points             | integer                | not null                                               | plain     
Indexes:
    "challenge_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "challengesolve" CONSTRAINT "challengesolve_challenge_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (challenge_id) REFERENCES challenge(id)

webserver=> \d+ challengesolve

    Column    |            Type             | Modifiers | Storage  
--------------+-----------------------------+-----------+---------
 team_id      | integer                     | not null  | plain   
 challenge_id | integer                     | not null  | plain   
Indexes:
    "challengesolve_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (team_id, challenge_id)
    "challengesolve_challenge_id" btree (challenge_id)
    "challengesolve_team_id" btree (team_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "challengesolve_challenge_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (challenge_id) REFERENCES challenge(id)
    "challengesolve_team_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (team_id) REFERENCES team(id)
```

The `team` and `challenge` tables should be fairly self explanatory. The `challengesolve` table is an intersection table indicating which teams have solved which challenges.

In short, I would like to find the three teams that have the most points. I am aware already that I can find the number of points a particular team has with a statement like

```
SELECT SUM(challenge.points) AS points 
FROM challengesolve 
INNER JOIN challenge
ON challenge.id = challengesolve.challenge_id 
WHERE challengesolve.team_id = 1;
```

How can I modify this query to find the top three teams?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: @D-Shih I would, except the accepted answer has already addressed the issue. Thank you for your interest regardless!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In short, I would like to find the three teams that have the most points.

You could use:

```
SELECT challengesolve.team_id,SUM(challenge.points) AS points 
FROM challengesolve 
INNER JOIN challenge
ON challenge.id = challengesolve.challenge_id 
GROUP BY challengesolve.team_id
ORDER BY points DESC
LIMIT 3;
```